# SSRS sort before group on in a row group

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I ran across this in a report that was grouping on incorrectly.

I had a group that grouped on a code, to get rid of duplicate codes. However, I also had a sort by date. My intention was to get the earliest code and remove all duplicates, however instead SSRS took it as get rid of duplicate codes, and then sort all of the results by date!

How could you add to the "group on" setting of a row group that you want only earliest date?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in SQL you can just group in the query:

```
SELECT Code, MIN(SomeDate) AS MinDate
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Code
ORDER BY Code
```